# How do I programmatically build server url?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I do not know how to build the server URL from server data without hardcoding it.

For example, with the class below, you can access the method GetLoginQRCode with the following URL in a browser: `http://localhost:5001/api/site`

In the method GetLoginQRCode I would like to build the URL to the login method.   I do not know how to get the data to build a URL like `http://localhost:5001/api/site/login`

Obviously `/login` can be hard coded.  But I do not want to hard code the `http` or the `localhost` nor the path `api/site`.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class SiteController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetLoginQRCode()
    {
        var thisServerloginUrl = "http://localhost:5001/api/dealer/login";

        /*
            what I would like is to programatically build the URL something like this
            var thisServerloginUrl = [whatever I need here] + "/login"
        */

        return Ok();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("login")]
    public IActionResult Login()
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can get all of that through server variables so that I do not have to hard code it?

**Edit**:  I am not redirecting the user to another URL.  I am going to generate a QR Code with the URL as the QR Code data.  The QR code will be returned as a result of calling the method `GetLoginQRode`.  I *DO NOT NEED* help with the Qr code as I have that working.  I didn't put it in the example to keep the code simple.

Comment: do you need the absolute url or will a realtive one work?

Comment: You can get the port and the domain address of the current host but this sort of approach won’t scale for multiple servers with load balancer scenarios.

Comment: @DanielA.White I need absolute because the URL would go into a QRCode that would be displayed to the user.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius  For now, I think the scalability isn't a concern.  But if there is a solution that works for both without too much work, that is ok too

Comment: you could put this into a configuration file

Comment: @react.dude.2 the application is not aware of the origin/domain, you will have to combine that manually (from the config) with my answer below.

Comment: @AvinKavish  ok.  I understand. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every controller has a property called `Url` which is set to an implementation of `IUrlHelper`. Use it to generate an absolute url. The application is not aware of it's own origin/domain or protocol. These cannot be reliably extracted from the request as the application could be behind proxies that alter headers and terminate ssl. Use a configuration value to add the protocol and domain to the URL.

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetLoginQRCode()
{

   // In same controller
   var url = Url.Action("Login")

   // or in Different Controller
   var url = Url.Action("Login", "Account")

   return Ok();
}
```

The [api reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.iurlhelper?view=aspnetcore-2.2) outlines all possible variants.

Comment: This is the correct answer, however it's important to keep in mind that the URL generated will be based on the http routes.  If there are multiple routes to your URL you may need to use a different method to get the correct url.

Comment: Url.Action("login") gives me `api/site/login' .  I need the full URL such as http://localhost:5001/api/site/login

Comment: That's upto you to add depending on the environment the application is running in.